# Play Video uploaded from iPhone on Android

Tags: android, iphone, android-view, iphone-video

I am creating an application in which I have to upload and play videos on both Android and iPhone but video uploaded from iPhone is not working on Android. It say's "Can't Play video"

What is the best solution to resolve this issue. Do I reduce the iPhone video upload quality and over come to this what should be the video specifications to run on both? Or do I need to go for other optional solution. Please suggest.

Android Target API 16.

Thanks

Comment: do you got solution for that ??? am also facing same problem so please would you like to help me ?

Comment: Yes Vaishali, We will go with FFMPEG Implementation at server end to fix that issue. We can also implement the same at device end too but you must have good command over NDK for the same. Also its a heavy process to we prefer to go with high config server only.

Comment: oh yes... at android side can we do it ? as you might be know about MX Player application ?
in that application video is played .. i want to do same stuff

Comment: MX Player is using some codec to play all kind videos. Sorry but I am not much comfortable with that part.

Comment: but i want to play video in my native app only..